# SQL Server 2008 R2: query RECENT locks, NOT current locks

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, locking

The database had average lock wait time of 30 seconds for a period of about a minute.
I didn't run my lock query in time to see what was happening.
I can't seem to find anything that shows recent locks, just current locks.

Comment: Use extended Events to get locks recorded. Or let the SQL Agent monitor the counter and run your script...

Answer (score 3):

some (most) X locks are recorded in the log, see [How to read and interpret the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/). You can see what xact acquired them and how long the xact lasted (see the link). You won't find the conflicts, but you can make some guess.